# How to store a dataset retrieved with Siphon and the ncss service

Tags: python-siphon

I use the Siphon library to retrieve a subset (using the ncss service) of a remote NetCDF dataset. Is there a convenient way of storing the result in a local .nc file or do I have to create a new Dataset for writing and then clone everything in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a query (`query`) and client (`ncss`) set up, then you can do something like this:

```
with open('mydata.nc', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(ncss.get_data_raw(query))
```